# Solution to the equation using the generalization of the Master Theorem

Tags: algorithm, math, proof, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

I ask help in explaining how the proof works. I've seen examples of it, but have trouble understanding it.

**Prove the following**

The solution to the equation

T(n) = aT(n/b) + Θ(n<sup>k</sup>  log<sup>p</sup> n) where a ≥ 1, b > 1, p ≥ 0

- **T(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub> a</sup>)      if a > b<sup>k</sup>**
- **T(n) = O(n<sup>k</sup> log<sup>p+1</sup> n)   if a = b<sup>k</sup>**
- **T(n) = O(n<sup>k</sup> log<sup>p</sup> (n))     if a < b<sup>k</sup>**

[Here is the screenshot of the question in a better format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CqZz.png)

This a generalization of the Master Theorem.

Comment: Are you asking; provide a proof for the master theorem?? That is well and truly a solved problem - p76 of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms

Comment: The question asks to prove the given theorem. I am unfamiliar with such theorem and I would appreciate an explanation as to how to approach the proof and why such proof is acceptable. I've already looked over other answers but have trouble understanding the concepts behind the proof.

Comment: Advice: go grab Introduction to Algorithms from the library and turn to p76. It's very good text. Very proofy.

Comment: I have read it but am having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Yeah the book is a little convoluted

Comment: May be if you want an explanation, describe what about existing published proofs you finding troubling.

Comment: The book shows a generalized explanation for O(n). Now I'm looking for how I apply a similar proof to O(n^k log^p n).

Answer (score 0):

For some x =log(n)/log(b) one has n=b<sup>x</sup>. Divide the equation by a<sup>x</sup>

> T(b<sup>x</sup>)/a<sup>x</sup> = T(b<sup>x-1</sup>)/a<sup>x-1</sup> + Θ((b<sup>k</sup>/a)<sup>x</sup>·x<sup>p</sup>·log<sup>p</sup> b)

The summation of terms m<sup>p</sup>·q<sup>m</sup> for m < x is

- bounded by a constant for q < 1
- growing like x<sup>p+1</sup> for q = 1
- dominated by the last term x<sup>p</sup>·q<sup>x</sup> for q > 1

Recognizing q=b<sup>k</sup>/a and substituting back gives the result

- for a < b<sup>k</sup>: T(b<sup>x</sup>)=O(a<sup>x</sup>), or T(n)=O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>)
- for a = b<sup>k</sup>: T(b<sup>x</sup>)=O(x<sup>p+1</sup>·a<sup>x</sup>), or T(n)=O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>·log<sup>p+1</sup>n )
- for a > b<sup>k</sup>: T(b<sup>x</sup>)=O(x<sup>p</sup>·b<sup>kx</sup>), or T(n)=O(n<sup>k</sup>·log<sup>p</sup>n)